# Check if second script is running or already finished

Tags: python, linux, process, tmux

I need to check if a `scriptA.py` is still running, in `scriptB.py`. Both are started individually, but `scriptB.py` may only continue if `scriptA.py` is still running.

I know I could use

```
import subprocess

process = subprocess.Popen(['pgrep', 'scriptA.py'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

process.wait()

if not process.returncode:
    print "Process running"
else:
    print "Process not running"
```

But script a runs in a tmux session. Which is called like `tmux new -d -s scriptA_2014-12-09-10-54-02-697559 'cd /home/user/scriptA; python scriptA.py -flag; echo $? > /tmp/scriptA_2014-12-09-10-54-02-697559'`

If i `pgrep scriptA.py` it doesn't return the `PID`. `pgrep tmux` would work, but that there might be other tmux sessions, so I can't use that.

I could do something like `ps aux | grep scriptA.py | wc -l` and check the line count - but this feels like it's very variable.

How else could I verify if `scriptA.py` is running?

Comment: You could implement a simple socket server in a separate thread of scriptA, and ping it from scriptB to see if it replies...

Comment: that would be possible, but it feels like an overkill. I've also considered writing the `PID` on script start to a file an reading it in the second one.

Comment: PID file seems like simplest fix here, anything else and you probably looking at the socket level or something like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm now using the `PID`, written to a file at script execution.. The code I use seems to work for my case:

In `scriptA`, at execution start:

```
pidf = open("./scriptA_pid.tmp","w")
pidf.write(str(os.getpid()))
pidf.close()
```

In `scriptB`, at the beginning of the loop that needs to be executed until `scriptA` is done.

```
with open("./scriptA_pid.tmp","r") as f:
    scriptA_pid = f.read()
chk_sA = subprocess.Popen(['kill -0 '+str(scriptA_pid)+' > /dev/null 2>&1; echo $?'],stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=devnull,shell=True)
chk_sA.wait()
sA_status = chk_sA.stdout.read()

if int(sA_status) == 0:
    #ScriptA is still running
    pass
else:
    #ScriptA is not running
    sys.exit(0)
```